# How can I serialize only the ID of a child

Tags: symfony, serialization

I'm looking for the correct way to serialize a child of my object.
I have the following classes:

```
class company {
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups ({"get"})
     */
    private $id;
}

class User {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     * @Groups ({"get"})
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Company::class, inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     * @Groups ({"get"})
     */
    private $company;
}
```

As soon as I use the serializer on a User object, I receive the following response.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "email": "email@mydomain.com",
    "company": {
        "id": 1
    }
}
```

But I prefer the following response, how can I get these?

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "email": "email@mydomain.com",
    "company": 1
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom normalizer, and summarise the company within the User - as it is being converted from the original object (with sub-entities) to an array, before being json-encoded.

```sh
symfony console make:serializer:normalizer [optional name, eg: 'UserNormalizer']
```

This creates a new class, with in part, the contents:

```php
     public function normalize($object, $format = null, array $context = []): array
     {
         // $object is a User entity at this point
         $data = $this->normalizer->normalize($object, $format, $context);

         // Here: add, edit, or delete some data
         // and we summarise the company entity to just the ID.
         $data['company'] = $object->getCompany()->getId();

         return $data;
     }
```

When I did this with a slightly more complex entity that referred back to the original one (if company had a reference back to a user), it made 'A circular reference', so I added an annotation to @Ignore the field in the User entity, for serialization purposes. It was still given to the normalizer, to use from the object passed into `normalize()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also serialize the result of a method instead:

```
class User {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     * @Groups ({"get"})
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Company::class, inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $company;

    /**
     * @Groups ({"get"})
     */
    public function getCompanyId()
    {
        return $this->company->getId();
    }
}
```